# Popup without tile in iOS

Tags: ios, uiactionsheet

I want to show popup if I click a button on toolbar. I am using ios 8 SDK.

I am using below code to do the same, but now I want to remove title from it.

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:[appDelegate encTitle]
                                                          delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                otherButtonTitles:@"Add Bookmark", @"Cancel",nil];
actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleDefault;
actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex = 1;  // make the second button red (destructive)
[actionSheet showInView:self.view]; // show from our table view (pops up in the middle of the table)
[actionSheet release];
```

If I use like this initWithTitle:@"" then also title block comes in the popup.

**currently it is like below image**

[image]

**want to achieve like this**

[image]

Please help me to fix the issue.

**After using UIalertviewController as suggested by sweetAngel, its coming like this in iPhone 4s....please help to show it properly in all the devices.**

[image]

Comment: For which OS version are you programming? It's been a while since Apple introduced ARC.

Comment: actually its a old code i am just compiling with 8....new to ios programming

Comment: UIActionSheet is deprecated in iOS 8, then how it is compiling.Instead use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using iOS 8, then you can try this one :

```
UIAlertController *alert1 = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Add Bookmark" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
    // Your code for bookmark
    [alert1 dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}];
UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
    [alert1 dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}];

[alert1 addAction:ok];
[alert1 addAction:cancel];
[self presentViewController:alert1 animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: now it works ....but in iPhone 4s simulators, add bookmark is partially visible and cancel is not shown at all....please help

Comment: please help with new issue...after using solution provided by you...updated question with new issue...

Comment: @user1010280, It's work perfect for me in 4s. You can check it out here "http://i61.tinypic.com/24pgguu.jpg"

Comment: Have you set frame for view of viewController from you are presenting this action sheet...?

Comment: Alternate solution : you can try by change `preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet` to `preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert`, if you do't mind with the design of layout.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79536/discussion-between-sweet-angel-and-user1010280).

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 8, not only you should definetely **not** use `retain` / `release`, but in order to present an action sheet you should use `UIAlertController` because `UIActionSheet` is deprecated. Here's an example:

```
UIAlertController *actionSheet = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Evacuate Building!" message:@"" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];



UIAlertAction *destructiveAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Kick through door" style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    // destructive action completion
}];

UIAlertAction *defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Walk calmly" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    // default action completion
}];

UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Do nothing" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    // cancel action completion
}];

[actionSheet addAction:destructiveAction];
[actionSheet addAction:defaultAction];
[actionSheet addAction:cancelAction];

[self presentViewController:actionSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
```